# Why my iphone swift app is allocate and using much memory?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am writing my whole app from code and i am not using storyboard.But My app is using much memory. I have some view controller,TableViewController, collectionView and some webview in my apps.

[image: Memory Uses picture.][image: Memory Allocation Instrument.]

And I am pushing all viewController and instantiating navigationViewController from RootviewController to it's childviewController.

And I am think that the ARC is not working is enable in my project.And When the memory reaches maximum my app is kill by iPhone.

Comment: We will need some more information related coding to help you out. Try out the instruments like "Allocations" and "Time Profiler" and then attach the screenshot.

Comment: Okay thank you Wolverine. just a minute i will attached.

Comment: check if you have any leaks, and when you start with telling us that everything is built from the code you probably messed something up with views

Comment: @DineshKatwal from your screenshots your checking memory leaks in simulator. that will show the memory of the system not the device. It is not accurate. So test your app in device not on simulator.

Comment: yes i am testing on simulator and it's showing memory too much.

Answer (score 1):

wow, that's a lot of memory!

I don't have much experience with webviews, but I might be able to help with the other components.

**As a suggestion:** Make use of the debugger to go through your code step by step and keep an eye on the memory inside XCode.

[image: Looks something like this. The same tool you used.]

You might be able to find out which part of your code generates so much memory usage that way.

**If you can't find the problem:** It is very hard to tell where this effect comes from. It might be a little easier if your post your code (preferably commented) so we can dig deeper into what might be causing this problem.

Cheers,
Ferdinand

Comment: No Problem! Let me know if you got the solution. If not, I might be able to help differently.

Comment: Yes i found problem with UIWebview after loading webview and finishing it's work it is not releasing memory I going to see how to release memory after finishing work wit uiwebview. For uiwebview my ARC is not working

Comment: `UIWebView` has some serious problems. Try `WKWebView` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much bro . WKWebview it use less memory.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

check if there are any memory retain cycles, when refrencing self inside closure always use weak reference.

Comment: Okay I found that after using UIWebview it's not releasing memory how can i release it.